# Partial derivative of y = wx + b

Tags: partial-derivative, neural-networks

I am reading from a book about neural network that first mentions a simple activation function of the following form.

$$ y = wx + b $$

$y$, $w$, $x$ and $b$ are all scalar real numbers.

Then it explains how a small change in $w$ and $b$ is going to affect the output $y$ with the following relationship.

$$ \Delta y = \frac{\delta y}{\delta w} \Delta w + \frac{\delta y}{\delta b} \Delta b $$

Could you please provide me a step by step proof of how this relationship follows from the first equation $y = wx + b$?

Comment: This is the [multivariable chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function, let us say $y$ that depends on $x$, $w$ and $b$, $i.e$ $y=y(x,w,b)$ the change of $y$ fixed $x$ due to a variation of $w$ and $b$ is defined infinetesimaly as:
$$dy = \frac{\partial y}{\partial w}dw+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}db$$

Comment: Is there a difference in meaning between the notation `\Delta y` and `dy`?

Comment: $\delta$ or $\Delta$ usually mean a finite (but small) increment. I think they wrote $\delta$ in analogy to $\partial$, and $\Delta$ to $d$. In any case the correct notation is the formula I gave you and the following: $$\Delta y = \frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\Delta w+\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}\Delta b$$